# RODBC connection issue

Tags: r, ms-access, lapply, rodbc

I am trying to use RODBC to connect to an access database. I have used the same structure several times in this project with success. However, in this instance it is now failing and I cannot figure out why. The code is not really reprex as I can't provide the DB, but...
This works for a single table:

```
library(magrittr);library(RODBC)
#xWalk_path is simply the path to the accdb
#xtabs generated by querying the available tables
x=1
tab=xtabs$TABLE_NAME[x]
temp<-RODBC::odbcConnectAccess2007(xWalk_path)%>% 
      RODBC::sqlFetch(., tab, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
odbcCloseAll()
#that worked perfectly
```

However, I really want to use this in a a function so I can read several similar tables into a list. As a function it does not work:

```
xWalk_ls<- lapply(seq_along(xtabs$TABLE_NAME), function(x, xWalk_path=xWalk_path, tab=xtabs$TABLE_NAME[x]){
#print(tab) #debug code
  temp<-RODBC::odbcConnectAccess2007(xWalk_path)%>% 
        RODBC::sqlFetch(., tab, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
   return(temp)
   odbcCloseAll()
 }) 
#error every time
```

The above code will return the error:

```
Warning in odbcDriverConnect(con, ...) :
  [RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLDriverConnect
Warning in odbcDriverConnect(con, ...) : ODBC connection failed
Error in RODBC::sqlFetch(., tab, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) : 
  first argument is not an open RODBC channel
```

I am baffled. I accessed the db to pull table names and generate the `xtabs` variable using `sql Tables`.  Also, earlier in my code I used a similar code structure (not identical, but same core: `sqlFetch` to retrieve a table into a list) nd it worked without a problem. Only difference between then and now is that: *Then* I was opening and closing different .accdb files, but pulling the same table name from each. *Now*, I am opening and closing the same .accdb file but pulling different sheet names each time.

Am I somehow opening and closing this too fast and it is getting irritated with me? That seems unlikely, because if I force it to `print(tab)` as the first line of the function it will only print the first table name. If it was getting annoyed about the speed of opening an closing I would expect it to print 2 table names before throwing the error.

Answer (score 0):

`return` returns its argument **and exits**, so the remaining code (`odbcCloseAll()`) won't be executed and the opened file (AccessDB) remains locked as you supposed.

Comment: Changing the order of `odbcCloseAll` and `return` still returns the same error. Commenting them out and just calling `temp` still returns the error.

Comment: Does pulling the `RODBC::odbcConnectAccess2007()` out of the `lapply` loop help?Handling the DB connection once per file (not for every `sqlFetch` = tab anew) should be sufficient.

Comment: Yes, that is ultimately what I did. I abandoned the function (it was ultimately unnecessary) and made it a pipe with the first call to the RODBC connection which piped into the loop.  I didn't post that, because I still want to know why the other approach did not work.

Comment: @TBP: the other approach created a connection for each TABLE_NAME (`lapply(seq_along(xtabs$TABLE_NAME), ...`) of the same connection=file instead of creating the connection only once (or in a superior loop) and looping through the table_names reusing the existing connection to `sqlFetch` from the various tables.